# Add an image in background and a text zone

Tags: latex

Well I'm a newbie in latex and I want to make a latex Curriculum Vitae.
I want to create a page with two parts

1. First part: an image from TOP to Bottom, and from left to the middle of the page
2. Second part: a text zone from from TOP to Bottom, and from middle of the page to the right

I have tried to create two columns but every time one of the columnes are put on the next pages :(

Do you have any advice or tips or answer to give me?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Do you only want a 1-page CV?

Comment: Yes, only one page

Answer (score 1):

For a single-page split-view display, you can set the content in a [`tabularx`](//ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) structure. The left-hand side contains an image with no height/depth. This allows you put anything in the right-hand side.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} X X @{}}
  \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+.7\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{%
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=\textheight]{example-image}} &
    \lipsum[1-3]
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

There are multiple ways of doing this. It all depends on whether you're stuck with a single page, or want to move to a bigger canvas.